# How can I automate finding games that had brilliant moves in it by a particular player on chess.com?

Tags: software

There's a feature on chess.com for highlighting brilliant moves. I have 30,000 games back to 2015 in one account before that statistics feature came online, and I'd love to hunt for any brilliant moves in the stack.

Is there a way to programmatically do that?

I checked the chess.com api, and getting game analysis details isn't one of the things provided.

[image]

Comment: I ended up making an html scraper to scrape our thousands of historical games and found some real beauties. The brilliant heuristic is great to reuse. It means a lot to save off some great moves from old friends. I’m compiling them into a physical “best of <friend>” gift for each of them.

Comment: Are you referring to a search of games played on chess.com or to looking for "brilliant" moves in games played elsewhere?

Comment: Ask chess.com support if their API can support it